# Cannot read Response Cookie from React Frontend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, axios

I have a login function in a Spring Boot Backend and I'm constructing the answer like:

```
ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);

List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
    .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
    .body(new UserInfoResponse(userDetails.getId(),
                               userDetails.getUsername(),
                               userDetails.getEmail(),
                               roles));}
```

With testing with postman I see the cookie is automatically stored, but with testing in the browser there is nothing stored. The logs don't show a SET_COOKIE in the header, so maybe this is the problem. Should I use a different way to create a Cookie instead of a ResponseCookie?
I'm using axios in React to login.

Comment: Did you mean [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)?

Comment: What logs do you mean? If you are talking about some in app logs then that could be because of the `HttpOnly` flag on the `set-cookie` header. Do you see the cookie in the developer tools network tab? Usually people don't put jwt tokens in the `set-cookie` header, rather in the `Authorization` header.